# react-native-firebase/messaging gets unhandled promise error on ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

i am  trying to make react-native-firebase/messaging to run on ios

i have made a succesfull connection to firebase on both Android and ios.

but when i send a push message on android the app shows the message withut any problems, but ios shows this error

"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'message.title')"

my code is here

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getPushMessage();
    
    requestUserPermission();

  },[])


  const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const permission = await messaging().requestPermission();

    if(await permission){
      console.log('got permission', permission)
    }
  }

  const getPushMessage = () => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log(remoteMessage)
      Alert.alert('message.title', 'message.body')
    });

    return unsubscribe
  }
```

hank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that firebase sends a different object to ios than android.